# Does Scalala provide straightforward way of inserting vector into matrix?

Tags: scala, vector, matrix, scalala

I am a bit lost among all those available operators -- so is there easy way to insert a entire row/column (vector) into a matrix?

I started thinking about creating a vector, converting it to array, joining it with matrix converted into array, and creating new matrix based on such combined array, but it looks even uglier than it sounds.

Comment: Any reason you're still using scalala and not [breeze](https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze)?

Comment: @dhg, "still"? I just started using it few days ago ;-). I didn't even find a word about breeze up till now. I will take a look, thank you. The question still holds than (for breeze as well).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
val m = DenseMatrix((1, 4, 10, 13), (2, 5, 11, 14), (3, 6, 12, 15))

val v = DenseVector(7, 8, 9)

val m2 = DenseMatrix.zeros[Int](3, 5)
m2(::, 0 to 1) := m(::, 0 to 1)
m2(::, 2) := v
m2(::, 3 to 4) := m(::, 2 to 3)
```

You'll find more information about basic [breeze](https://github.com/dlwh/breeze) functionality [here](https://github.com/dlwh/breeze/wiki/Quickstart).

Comment: Thank you, also for nice way to initialize matrix, I didn't know about it.